# sails.js - How can I specify an order to the routes of installable hooks?

Tags: sails.js

I have a few policies that I'm trying to convert to installable hooks.
One in particular is the authentication step that adds a session variable for who the user is. I need to ensure that it fires first because subsequent hooks/controllers look at the session to determine who the user is.

The docs on routes ( https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/hookspec/routes.md ) say that I can specify if I want to run the route before or after all the custom routes, but I don't see a way to specify one hook before another hook.

I tried adding a "sails.on" in the initialize step of my two hooks as specified in the initialize docs ( https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/hookspec/initialize.md ). While it did alter the order of the initialize phase, it didn't seem to have any impact on the order that routes were handled.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this has been requested, but not implemented yet https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2517

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, there's no way to re-order hooks at the moment, but that doesn't mean you can't accomplish your goal in another way.  The `routes` feature of hooks is very convenient, but in this case you will need to bind your routes using events, and then make your hooks dependent on each other to ensure that the routes load in the correct order.  Many of the core Sails hooks work in just this way.

If you want to ensure that the hook `firsthook` to loads all of its routes before `secondhook`, you would put the following as the `initialize` method of `firsthook`:

```
initialize: function(cb) {

    sails.on('router:before', function () {

        sails.router.bind(routePath1, routeFn1);
        sails.router.bind(routePath2, routeFn2);
        sails.router.bind(routePath3, routeFn3);
        etc...

    });

}
```

And then do the same in `secondhook`, but wrapped in a `sails.after` block:

```
initialize: function(cb) {

    sails.after('hook:firsthook:loaded', function() {

        sails.on('router:before', function () {

            sails.router.bind(routePath1, routeFn1);
            sails.router.bind(routePath2, routeFn2);
            sails.router.bind(routePath3, routeFn3);
            etc...

        });

    }

}
```

Note that `sails.after` can accept either a single event name or an array to wait for.

Comment: Once again @sgress454 You did not disappoint :).
For others that are attempting to use his solution, don't overlook the `sails.on('router:before'...)` as I did at first. `sails.router.bind` won't work until after the router is loaded. This accomplishes exactly what I needed.
Thanks again!